# error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'uiOptions' in package 'android'

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-fragments

I have this configuration for my application.

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
```

I try to add the following...

```
<application android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow">
```

I get the following error....

```
[aapt] /home/jackie/Development/Code/personal/Android/ApaShooter/AndroidManifest.xml:9: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'uiOptions' in package 'android'
```

More info....

using android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think anyone could have answered this but in case...

My problem was related to the build.xml being built for a lower target.

I ran >android update project -p ./ -t 14

This seemed to fix it

Comment: I think this was my problem too, but I think because I'm using eclipse I can't say for sure. I tried changing from API11 to API14 using menu clicks Project->Properties->ProjectBuildTarget. That didn't help. Then I changed my manifest from version 14 to 15 and that fixed it. Can't recreate it though, but thought I'd write this in case it helps anyone. And yes, I changed my manifest back to 14 and it still works.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure that `android:uiOptions` is part of the support package, but I may be wrong. If not, compile against Android 4.0+. XML will fail silently.

Comment: I don't understand, I believe I am compiling against android 4.0 my tag is ...<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
     android:targetSdkVersion="14" />